# Are there any of NX-OS switchport "meta tags" alike features?

Tags: switchport, nx-os

I believe I once stumbled across an NX-OS feature which we currently need, but for the sake of it, I can't remember the details like platform (100V, 5000, 7000) or version. We are currently using 5600's with version 7.3.5 for our leafs.

Under a regular port configuration mode, you could add meta information tags, i.e. for billing purposes or whatever you liked. I do NOT mean the interface "description" field. We would need to define a format for our purpose and also it's limited to 80 characters.

I.e the config would look like this

```
interface xyz
 description i do not mean the description field
 port meta-tag CUSTOMER RED
 port meta-tag PRICE 1
```

The "port meta-tag" is made up to illustrate what i'm looking for and also because I can't remember. Also these meta information are meant to be read via snmp usually...

Actually, I just got the idea, maybe it's a specific feature I need to activate that I'm looking for...?

Regards,
Emanuel